# how can I make the process of checking urls faster?

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, url

I have to check 1,000,000 URLs as a part of a project and they have randomly been selected to either be valid or invalid. I have written the code and it's working and stuff, but I was wondering if there is a way I can make this better i.e. faster/more efficient.

I don't know much about this world of efficiency, but I have heard the word multithreading thrown around, would that help and how do I do that?

```
import requests
# url = "http://*******/(number from 1 to 1,000,000)"
available_numbers = []

for i in range(1,1000000):
    url = f"http://*************/{i}"
    data = requests.get(url)

    if data.status_code == 200:
        available_numbers.append(i)

print(available_numbers)
```

Comment: Ya, multithreading would definitely be the way to go. Use `from multiprocessing.Pool import ThreadPool`, start it up with with a 1000 or so threads, then submit jobs to it using `map` or `apply`. Be aware though that sending out 1000 concurrent requests to a server may get you rate-limited/blacklisted.

Comment: @Carcigenicate okay, I will look into that. Is the rate-limiting thing, automatic or do people have to implement that?? I mean this is just an assignment, so I don't think it will be a big problem, but just asking because I am a curious little cat, where can I learn more about this blacklisting and throttling?

Comment: That depends on a lot. Rate limiting could be implemented in the server, or by who ever is hosting the server. And just Googling should be sufficient. It will likely only be implemented in larger sites, but also be aware, you may accidentally DoS the website you're sending requests to if they're a small site.

Comment: oh, okay, thank you, I definitely don't wanna do that lol. Dossing would be terrible. I was just curious, thanks for letting me know and spreading the knowledge!